# Cannot connect to a Macintosh computer on the same network via hostname. Works with IP address

Tags: linux, macos, networking, wireless-networking, ssh

I’m trying to connect two Machintosh computers using SSH via their hostname. Both computers are running Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.2. And both computers connected via a Telus branded [Actiontec T1200H ADSL Wi-Fi router](http://www.actiontec.com/315.html) (PDF of the manual [available here](http://static.telus.com/common/cms/files/internet/telus_t2200h_user_manual.pdf)).

When running this SSH command with the computer hostname:

```
ssh macbookpro.local
```

I am get the following message:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname macbookpro.local: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

But if I run an SSH command with the computer’s IP address:

```
ssh 10.10.1.12
```

It works.

And I’ve found out so far that it’s a firewall issue; if I switch firewall off on both computers SSH connection works. But how can I establish SSH connection using computer hostnames while having the firewall enabled? And is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

How are these two Macintosh computers connected? Via a router? The way hostnames like `macbookpro.local` work is they are broadcast on the network via [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/index.html) which is simply Apple’s fancy name for broadcast/multicast network services:

> Bonjour, also known as zero-configuration networking, enables
>   automatic discovery of devices and services on a local network using
>   industry standard IP protocols.

So if these two Macintosh computers are on the same network sharing the same router, if that router is blocking broadcast/multicast network services then the hostname `macbookpro.local` will not be able to be found since it will be blocked from the router.

The first think I would recommend is that you login to your router—whatever model it might be—and tool around the menus to see of a broadcast/multicast option is set to filter or block broadcast/multicast traffic. But looking at the details on your router—[Actiontec T1200H ADSL Wi-Fi router](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/index.html) (PDF of the manual [available here](https://superuser.com/a/880624/167207))—it does not seem there is even a way to block broadcast/multicast network traffic. So my next idea would be to see if somehow there are firewall settings in the Macintosh’s themselves getting in the way of Bonjour not working? Might be worth it to disable the firewall to at least test the theory for now.

Looking at the firewall options I have in my Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks) install, it seems that unchecking the “Block all incoming connections” checkbox while the firewall is enabled will allow your firewall to be active while still allowing Bonjour services to be passed through to the system.

When the firewall is on click on the “Firewall Options…” button and you will see this screen with that “Block all incoming connections” checkbox:

[image]

On a related note, you can debug this stuff—as explained [in this answer I posted here](https://superuser.com/a/880624/167207)—by testing the network with `arp` and `dns-sd` from the Mac OS X “Terminal” like this. For example, to use [`arp`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/arp.8.html) to see what devices are on the network just type in this command and hit <kbd>return</kbd>:

```
arp -a
```

The output returned if broadcast/multicast traffic is being sent to your computer would be something like this:

```
computer-name.local (123.456.789.0) at 00:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.2.2) at bb:88:99:cc:77:aa on bridge100 ifscope [bridge]
```

That shows me that `computer-name.local` has an IP address of `123.456.789.0` and the bridged connection used by the ad-hoc network where I am sharing my Ethernet connection via Wi-Fi is `192.168.2.2`.

And you can also use [`dns-sd`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dns-sd.1.html) (Multicast DNS (mDNS) & DNS Service Discovery (DNS-SD) Test Tool) from the “Terminal” like this to see if your computer is picking up the hostname of the other machine:

```
dns-sd -q [name of computer].local
```

This assumes you know the name of the computer already and broadcast/multicast is working; replace `[name of computer].local` with that computer name. Then the output would be something like this; note the `123.456.789.0` is a fake IP address for example’s sake:

```
    Timestamp     A/R Flags if Name                          Type  Class   Rdata
19:56:22.856  Add     2  4 [name of computer].local.               Addr   IN     123.456.789.0
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your reply! Computers are connected via wi-fi router which also gives me internet (If I understand it right))) `arp -a` gives me no computer names - only ? and IPs.. and `dns-sd -q macbookpro.local` gives me : `DATE: ---Fri 27 Feb 2015---
20:28:58.319  ...STARTING...` So I think you are right! But it's kinda not clear what's wrong with router settings

Comment: the router I've got from Telus. Actiontec model: T1200H. I've logged in but there is no "broadcast/multicast traffic" option.

Comment: It says: Firewall - NAT only (no clue what does that mean), Blocking/Filtering - Disabled; UPnP (WTF?) - Enabled

Comment: I also have another device connected to router - to give me 5G speed (As I understand there are no routers so far which can give 5G without this additional device - not sure how does it called), but there is no such an option in it neither...(((

Comment: Well - I've tried to disable firewalls on both machines and now it works!!! But wait - wth???? It worked before even with firewall switched on! Should I disable it any time before I want to use ssh??? It's not normal..

Comment: Thank you. That is strange, because it's unchecked on both computers and it still doesn't work with firewall enabled(((( Should I add maybe something like "allow Bonjour incomming connection"???

Comment: I'll mark this temporary as solved until someone can explain how to use ssh with firewall on OS X Yosemite 10.10.2

Answer (score 0):

`macbookpro.local` is probably your LocalHostName; 1 of the 3 computer names used by Mac OS X (`HostName`, `LocalHostName` and `ComputerName`). If I remember correctly, it’s used for either Bonjour or AFP.

`ssh` on the other hand uses the IP protocol and is not Mac OS X specific. It will attempt to resolve your “hostname” with DNS. You can find your hostame by using the following command:

```
scutil --get HostName
```

or simply:

```
hostname
```

Conversely, you can also use `localhost` if you're connecting back to your own computer.

Comment: thank you for reply but it's kinda useless... I know this: `ComputerName` -- User-friendly name for the system (in System Preferences -> Sharing -> Computer Name)
`LocalHostName` -- The local (Bonjour) host name (in System Preferences -> Sharing -> press 'Edit')
`HostName` -- Can see it in Terminal prompt (\h or \H) Associated with hostname and gethostname. And you are wrong -- Local Host Name is the one you need to use with ssh